# Order of complexity of a matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication, code-complexity

I need some help answering this question : How do I find the complexity of the matrix B and f knowing that I have this code :

```
d = 123456; 
randn('state',d); rand('state',d);
n = 1000; A = diag(1+rand(1,n));
k = 5500; r = randperm(n*n,k);
A(r) = A(r) + rand(1,k);
L = tril(A); U = A-L;

x = rand(n,1);
b = A*x;

B = -L\U; f = L\b;

xit = zeros(n,1);
nit = 100;
res = zeros(nit,1);
incr = zeros(nit,1);
err = zeros(nit,1);
for it = 1:nit,
   xit0 = xit;
   xit = B*xit+f;
   res(it) = norm(b-A*xit);
   incr(it) = norm(xit-xit0);
   err(it) = norm(xit-x);
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you call "Complexity" for a matrix? And for a vector?

Comment: Data structures do not have a time complexity. Computational algorithms applied to the data structures do. For example, multiplying a *m* x *n* matrix by a *n* x 1 column vector is is *O(m\*n)*. `mldivide` as used in `B = -L\U` is a bit more complex as you can see in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt4jslc-6).